# BCM43142 chipset, wifi is good no monitor mode, no packet injection

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a problem with my Broadcom BCM43142 chipset[14:e4;4365]. I can easily connect to wifi networks but I can't go in monitor mode properly, I mean when I use airmon-ng I can use prism0 interface to capture packets, I can't also do packet injection.
This problem is on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS hp laptop. if the problem is not clear yet ask me to explain.
I will appreciate your help a lot.